# Get name of List or Data Extension from within an Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am trying to figure out if I can use AMPScript in the body of an email to find out the name of the List or Data Extension the email is being sent to and then do something based on which condition is met. Does that make sense?

So basically, if I am sending an email and my Data Extension name is DE1 then do something in AMPScript. If it's DE2, do something different.

Comment: There's an Idea proposed to get the _DataSourceName populated with the Entry Data Extension for Journey Builder sends! https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000001HkZRQA0 You can upvote it if you feel like this would be something useful down the road!

Comment: I Upvoted it! @D4MG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `_DataSourceName` [**personalization string**](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings).

> This value captures any audience object sent to. This covers lists, data extensions, groups, and filters.

Usage:

```
%%[

if _DataSourceName == "DE1" then

  /* something for DE1 */

else

  /* something for DE2 */ 

endif

]%%
```

You may need to experiment with it if your send is every sent to more than one DE.

**Update 2020-07-07**

You can get a bunch of info about journey interactions via [**REST API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm).  It'll give you all the details about the send context and email definition, etc.  Technically, you could pull this data in an Automation with a Script Activity and store it in a DE.  Similar to [**this**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/), except with a REST call instead of WSProxy retrieve on the SOAP object.

Comment: Dude you are awesome. How come I couldn't find that in the docs? Is this kind of stuff listed anywhere?

Comment: The [**Personalization Strings**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) and [**AMPScript Functions**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm) pages are my most frequently visited links.

Comment: Yes I looked there but did not see it.

Comment: @AdamSprings so this has been really helpful in the past. I found it doesn't work with Journeys. Do you have any experience with that? For some reason, in a journey you'd think it would reference the entry point DE, but it references All Subscribers

Comment: @garek007 I know it's a long shot, but were you able to figure out a way to get a reference to the entry point DE ? (working on a Journey too)

Comment: @gabriel-kaam unfortunately no

Comment: Since Journey sends are triggers, you may have noticed that the auto-created TSDs don't have DEs associated with them, which makes sense that the `_dataSourceName` isn't populated.

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer above.